# Google DFP creatives randomly display although correct ad tags are accessed

Tags: android, ios, admob, adsense, google-dfp

I am using Google DFP (DoubleClick for Publishers) ads for android
and iPhone devices, I want to display ads on a specific screen sizes
for an app in ios and android in LANDSCAPE MODE. I have created an order then I have
created a line item for that order and inside that line item, I
created "creatives" of various sizes according to physical sizes of
the screens for both ios and android. Then I went to inventory and
got ad tags for all the creatives and incorporated them in my apps
separated by size checks.

Now the issue I am facing is that in code, although the correct ad
tag is accessed but the creative(image) I specified for that tag is
randomly picked. This issue exists both in android and iPhone.

I want to know why not only the specified size creative (image) is picked? 
Is it necessary to separate the iPhone and Android inventories (creatives)?

I have also tried the smart banner sizes and cutom banner sizes but
specified creative not displayed.

ref smart banners: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-
sdk/docs/dfp/android/banner#smart

ref custom banners: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-
sdk/docs/dfp/android/banner#custom_size

Also, when I turn on test ads, they appear on the whole width of any device but my ads are not displayed on the whole width. Although if the test ad is smaller from the width of the device, then it automatically adds some background on both sides of the ad to fill the whole width. but this not occur when my creatives are displayed.

codes for Android and iPhone:
Android: To pick respective screen size ads

```
    Fragment frag=new AdBannerFragment();
ArrayList<Integer> screenSize=Globals.getScreenSize

(getActivity());
Integer width=screenSize.get(0);
if (width==120) {

frag = new AdBannerFragment

("/235389899/Clubfitting-Update-15_320x50-120dpi");
} else if (width==160) {
frag = new AdBannerFragment

("/235389899/Clubfitting-Update-15_320x50-160dpi");
} else if (width==240) {
frag = new AdBannerFragment

("/235389899/Clubfitting-Update-15_320x50-240dpi");
} 
else if (width==320) {
// frag = new AdBannerFragment

("/235389899/Clubfitting_4-14_320x50");
frag = new AdBannerFragment

("/235389899/Clubfitting-Update-15_320x50-320dpi");
} else if (width==480) {
// frag = new AdBannerFragment

("/235389899/Clubfitting_4-14_480x50");
frag = new AdBannerFragment

("/235389899/Clubfitting-Update-15_320x50-480dpi");

} else if (width==640){
// frag = new AdBannerFragment

("/235389899/Clubfitting_4-14_640x100");
frag = new AdBannerFragment

("/235389899/Clubfitting-Update-15_320x50-640dpi");
}else{
frag = new AdBannerFragment

("/235389899/Clubfitting-Update-15_320x50-640dpi");
}
```

AdBanner Fragment code(To set and load banners):

```
AdSize customAdSize = new AdSize(AdSize.FULL_WIDTH, 50);
adView = new PublisherAdView(activity2);
//I have also tried smart banners.
adView.setAdSizes(customAdSize);
mAdContainer.addView(adView);
adView.setAdUnitId(mTag);
adView.loadAd(new PublisherAdRequest.Builder

().build());
```

iPhone: To pick respective screen size ads

```
CGSize screenSize;

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0"))
    {
        screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].nativeBounds.size;
    }
    else
    {
        screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    }

    NSLog(@"screen size: %@ banner frame: %@",NSStringFromCGSize(screenSize),NSStringFromCGSize(self.bannerVw.frame.size));

    if (screenSize.width== 1920)
    {
        self.bannerVw.adUnitID = @"/235389899/Clubfitting-Update-15_736x90";
        self.bannerVw.adSize = GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSizeMake(736, 90));
    }
    else if (screenSize.width== 1334)
    {
        self.bannerVw.adUnitID = @"/235389899/Clubfitting-Update-15_667x50";
        self.bannerVw.adSize = GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSizeMake(667, 50));
    }
    else if (screenSize.width== 1136)
    {
        self.bannerVw.adUnitID = @"/235389899/Clubfitting-Update-15_568x50";
        self.bannerVw.adSize = GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSizeMake(568, 50));
    }
    else if (screenSize.width== 960)
    {
        self.bannerVw.adUnitID = @"/235389899/Clubfitting-Update-15_480x50";
        self.bannerVw.adSize = GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSizeMake(480, 50));
    }
    else     //default
    {
        self.bannerVw.adUnitID = @"/235389899/Clubfitting-Update-15_736x90";
        self.bannerVw.adSize = GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSizeMake(736, 90));
    }
```

AdBanner Fragment code(To set and load banners):

```
self.bannerVw.rootViewController = self;

//I am currently using custom sizes and check smart anners also. 

//    self.bannerVw.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape;
    [self.bannerVw setDelegate:self];
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
//    request.testDevices = @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID ];
    [self.bannerVw loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Yes.. Good question... I am facing the same issue... Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you found any workaround? I have the very same issue. I found that if you create creatives with different height, it is picked properly (and if you have a bannerView of the missing height, it won't load at all).

So it seems that DFP doesn't take banner width into account – only height.

Comment: You are definitely misunderstanding the DFP Inventory and Orders. You can fit everything inside 1 or 2 ad units. and have many orders (Line Items) as you need. In 'Line Items' specify each size you want to show in your apps. Shortly 1-2 ad units->Orders (Line Items)->creatives with multiple sizes. DFP will show the highest priority that fits into your View with AdSize from creatives

Comment: @Galymzhan DFP will not show the highest priority that fits into view, i have practically tested this. if you are right please prove.

Comment: @SaadBilal priority is set in the Line Items settings, checkout [this screenshot](http://joxi.ru/krD1BdLH6X6qmp) and [the description](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/177279?hl=en)

Comment: @GalymzhanSh thanks mate!